# Firefox cannot find website servers, what is wrong?

Tags: 12.10, wireless, firefox, internet, firewall

Recently, I tried to access the internet using Firefox.  I have a good wifi signal according to the toolbar at the top, but Firefox says "Firefox can't find the server at`www.example.com`."  I tried disabling UFW, but that did nothing.  What exactly is happening that is preventing Firefox from accessing the internet, and how can I fix this issue?

I'm using Ubuntu 12.10, and the machine is a Compaq Presario CQ62.

NOTE:  Just before the issue, Firefox installed an update.  Also, I did not use the computer for a month or so before this issue, and the last time I used it there was no such issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is quite generic, so here are some tips:

- Have you checked your Firefox's network settings?

  - What about proxy settings?
  - Do you use something like Foxyproxy?
- You may try accessing the web from different tool/browser (Chrome, wget). Is it working?

  - If no, it problem in your network connection and not firefox itself.
- Execute following command to check the DNS lookup: "nslookup www.example.com"

It would be nice having more information. So I just hope that this will help a little...

Comment: you might also use the following command to ascertain 100% internet connectivity. type in a terminal window text between, but not including the quotes "ping google.com"  results similar to text in braces are good result {PING google.com (74.125.228.0) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from iad23s05-in-f0.1e100.net (74.125.228.0): icmp_req=1 ttl=252 time=16.0 ms}

Answer (score 0):

I had same sort of problems with all the browsers. I resolved it with this. After running this once in terminal, It could access normally through the browser.

Try this in Terminal :

```
firefox http://www.example.com
```

Answer (score 0):

There are problems with firefox like it can't connect to server or can't find server so to fix it if you are using a proxy server,make sure that it connects to the internet,your Internet security software is not blocking connections to the internet and if using wireless connection,make sure that you are connected to the right access point.